# Angular 12 Data path "" must NOT have additional properties (styleext)

Tags: angular-cli, angular12

What is wrong with the new version of Angular? Angular CLI 12.0.1 can't create new application. Tried to run `ng new twelveApp` and the cli complains dying **Data path "" must NOT have additional properties (styleext)**.

I have tried to set the ng-new schema additionalProperties to true but the error remains.

How to get rid of this additional property?

PS: back to @angular/cli@11.0.5  everything works quite perfectly.

Comment: I created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20945) for this.

Comment: in case you are using angular13 Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70344098/data-path-must-not-have-additional-propertiesextractcss-in-angular-13-while

Comment: @Arun VC Have the same issue but the problem is with "styleext"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on the answer to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20945), I edited `.angular-config.json` file in my home directory and removed the `schematics` section as shown below. Your particular case might require a variation of this solution.

```json
{
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do this have any secondary effects on the project?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: The section configures the behaviour of `ng generate` as documented [here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#generation-schematics). Therein, the [json schema](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/application/schema.json) is linked and doesn't contain a field `styleext` _in the latest version_.

Comment: None of these is working for me. I'm using angualr 13. Any ideas on how to get this rexolved?

Comment: Oh. It's the `.angular-config.json` in my HOME directory ( `/users/Username/.angular-config.json` ). I thought it was the `angular.json` of my project's directory.

Answer (score 69):

Try to change

```
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  },
```

to

```
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
```

In angular.json. Let me know if this works.

Comment: This works great in angular 12, styleext works in angular 6.x

Comment: This is the right answer for angular 12. Thanks!

Comment: This is the right answer for >= Angular 12

Comment: Wish this was my issue... My variable was already `style`

Comment: im already on style :(

Comment: works with Angular 13.x.x

Answer (score 14):

`styleext` has been renamed to only `style` a while ago (see [Farhans answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68442361/2410151)), so maybe that's your issue

Comment: Thx, change  the line "styleext :"sccs" for "style":"scss" works for me !

Answer (score 5):

open file:

`angular.json`
and change the

`"styleext": "scss"`

to:
`"style": "scss"`, like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in angular.json, remove this entry:

```
"extractCss": true,
```

This fixed my build in Angular: 13.1.2

Answer (score 0):

1. open your angular.json file
2. delete these lines of code (you might find them written twice )

   "schematics": {
   "@schematics/angular:component": {
   "styleext": "scss"
   }
   },

Answer (score 0):

Edit your **angular.json** file (most likely located at the root of your project) and look for the **schematics** object. Remove the property **styleext: "css"** because it is not a valid property for your project.

**Before edit**

```
"@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    }
```

**After edit**

```
"@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove it from my global angular cli settings to get it working. You can see your global config using this command "ng config -g"

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**angular.json**

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:application": {
      "strict": true
    }
  },
```

Comment: Please use comments to explain why you are suggesting the changes your propose and/or how your suggestion solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Open this path `C:\Users\yourUserNameOnWindows\.angular-config.json` if your user is A you write: `C:\Users\A\.angular-config.json` it will open JSON file, delete this from the file:

```json
{
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the answer provided above by mhusaini, please check the `angular.json` file within your angular project. You'll see a structure similar to:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-angular-app": {
      ...
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The solution variant required removing the content from within the `schematics` element.

Answer (score -2):

Open this path C:\Users\your user name

then you will find **.angular-config.json**

**Kill it ;)**

Comment: could you explain ?

Answer (score -3):

"schematics": {
"@schematics/angular:component": {
"prefix": "app",
//  "styleext": "scss"  // Change this to below value this works for me.
"style": "scss"
},
"@schematics/angular:directive": {
"prefix": "app"
}
},

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it