# Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(extractCss) in Angular 13 while upgrading project

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade, angular13

I am facing an issue while upgrading my project from angular 8.2.1 to angular 13 version.

After a successful upgrade while preparing a build it is giving me the following error.

```
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(extractCss).
```

I already renamed `styleext`  with `style` in the angular.json file, but still not able to find the root cause for this error.

**angular.json file is as follows.**

```
  {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "qiwkCollaborator": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {

        /*  "configurations": {
            "fr": {
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/qwikCollaborator/fr/",
            "i18nFile": "src/translate/messages.fr.xlf",      
            "i18nFormat": "xlf",      
            "i18nLocale": "fr",      
            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"    
             },
             "en": {
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/qwikCollaborator/en/",
            "i18nFile": "src/translate/messages.en.xlf",      
            "i18nFormat": "xlf",      
            "i18nLocale": "en",      
            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"    
             }  
           },*/
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/qiwkCollaborator",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/css/custom-mobile.css",
              "src/assets/css/custom.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/qwikCollaborator.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
          "es5": {
        "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.es5.json"
      },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
         /*  "configurations": {
            "fr": {
            "browserTarget": "qwikCollaborator:build:fr" 
            },
            "en": {
            "browserTarget": "qwikCollaborator:build:en" 
            } ,
            },*/
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "qiwkCollaborator:build"
          },
         
          "configurations": {
          "es5": {
        "browserTarget": "qiwkCollaborator:build:es5"
      },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "qiwkCollaborator:build:es5"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "qiwkCollaborator:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": ["../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "qiwkCollaborator:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "qiwkCollaborator:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "qiwkCollaborator"
}
```

How to get rid of this additional property?

can anyone help me with this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post your angular.json

Comment: @MehyarSawas added, please check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 12 Data path "" must NOT have additional properties (styleext)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67665753/angular-12-data-path-must-not-have-additional-properties-styleext)

Comment: @Bellash I have the same issue except that i am using angular 13 and none of the solutions prescribe online so far has worked for me

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Just remove the `"extractCss": true` from your production environment, it will resolve the problem.

The reason about it is extractCss is deprecated, and it's value is true by default.
See more here: [Extracting CSS into JS with Angular 11 (deprecated extractCss)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67209871/extracting-css-into-js-with-angular-11-deprecated-extractcss)

Comment: Have the same issue but mine has to do with "styleext". will the same solution apply?

Comment: I had the same issue with "sourceMap" and the same solution applied.

Comment: when i remove extractCss from my angular.json,  some scss adjustments from my project got broke