# Updating from Angular11 to 13 generates error Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(styleext)

Tags: angular-schematics, angular13

I have checked out the following [prescriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67665753/angular-12-data-path-must-not-have-additional-properties-styleext) for this problem and they did not resolve my issue. I upgraded from angular 11 to 13 following the procedure on the Angular official website which went well. Then Itried to generate a component and the issues started.

Answer (score 0):

Run this at the command prompt: "ng config -g schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext undefined"